# changing rigidbody.mass value in unity 3 D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am trying to change mass of a 3D object programmatically. But the object doesn't get the calculated mass but a 0 value initially. When the prefab of the object is created it gets the calculated mass of the previous object not the current mass. And the scenario repeats for all the prefabs created henceforth. How can I get around this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works like expected. Can you please show some code?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a get component call:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float mass;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.mass = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To give your rigidbody a mass can use the following script wise

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class example : MonoBehaviour {
    void Example() {
        rigidbody.mass = 0.5F;
    }
}
```

Next time do some more research.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-mass.html
Google first hit.